# Using GAE's search API with ndb's tasklets

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

The Google AppEngine search API can return [asynchronous results](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/#Python_Peforming_asynchronous_operations).  The docs say very little about these futures, but they do have a `.get_result()` method which looks *a lot* like an [`ndb.Future`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/futureclass).  I thought it would be fun to try to use one in a tasklet:

```
@ndb.tasklet
def async_query(index):
    results = yield [index.search_async('foo'), index.search_async('bar')]
    raise ndb.Return(results)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  `ndb` doesn't like this because the future returned by the search API doesn't seem to be compatible with `ndb.Future`.  However, the tasklet documentation also specifically mentions that they have been made to work with [`urlfetch` futures](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async#urlfetch).  Is there a way to get similar behavior with the search api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there *is* a way to make this work (at least, my tests on the dev_appserver seem to be passing ;-).

```
@ndb.tasklet
def async_query(index, query):
    fut = index.search_async(query)
    yield fut._rpc
    raise ndb.Return(fut._get_result_hook())
```

Now if I want to do multiple queries and intermix some datastore queries (i.e. maybe I use search API to get IDs for model entities),

```
@ndb.tasklet
def get_entities(queries):
    search_results = yield [async_query(q) for q in queries]
    ids = set()
    for search_result in search_results:
        for doc in search_results.results:
            ids.add(doc.doc_id)
    entities = yield [FooModel.get_by_id_async(id_) for id_ in ids_]
    raise ndb.Return(entities)
```

This is super hacky -- and I doubt that it is officially supported since I am using internal members of the async search result class ... Use at your own risk :-).